# How to find out object Interface class pointer when Object clicked on scene?

Tags: c++, qt, stl, qgraphicsscene, qlist

In scene I am dropping objects and creating objects(different types of object like dial,plot,thermometer) through Object Interface Class. I have to change the properties of object through Object Interface class. But when a object selected on scene how to find out object Interface class pointer? Any ideas are welcome...

```
       #include "ObjectInterfaceClass"

       if(event->mimeData()->text() == "Plot")
       {
        ObjInterfaceClass * pObjInterface = new ObjInterfaceClass ;

        const QMimeData *mime = event->mimeData();
        QByteArray itemData = mime->data(itemlistMimeType());
        QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QVariant width ,height ;
        dataStream >> width >> height ;

        pObjInterface->mObjProperety.geometry.height = height.toInt() ;
        pObjInterface->mObjProperety.geometry.width = width.toInt() ;
        pObjInterface->mObjProperety.geometry.xPos = event->pos().x() ;
        pObjInterface->mObjProperety.geometry.yPos = event->pos().y() ;
        pObjInterface->SetGraphicsScene((void*)scene);
        pObjInterface->CreateObject(CUSTOM_PLOT_NAME) ;
        pObjInterface->DrawObject();
      }
```

For more details[image of objects dropped on scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVEnU.png)
or How can I assign object interface pointer with object ?

Comment: Possibly you can get it with the following call: `this->metaObject()->className()` (or change this to the QObject that has been selected).
However if you want better answer you should provide more code

Comment: @Amfasis this will get only class name.... actually i want object interface pointer....

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread, but in that case you should definitely provide more code. I think you might get somewhere with a singleton (search google), but who knows what other solutions your code might reveal

Comment: @Amfasis Thanks ... singleton may help ..can u explain how can i apply singleton .... any example or reference

Comment: @Amfasis you are telling to make Object Interface class as singleton class... from the one instance create objects....

Comment: Again, more code might get better answers. A Singleton can be made via [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1098119)